# How to check what value of ValidateSet has been chosen without retyping that value in "if" block as literal?

Tags: powershell

Is there some kind of array that keeps all the values you specify for ValidateSet? I wouldn't want to copy a value of concern in "if" block to check whether it is equal to the value chosen by the user.

Let's take the following example:

```
function Get-MyValue
{ param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet("someLongLongOption1",
                     "someLongLongOption2",
                     "someLongLongOption3")]
        [string]$myOption)
}
```

What I can do now to check whether option 2 has been selected is `if($myOption -eq "someLongLongOption2")`. But how I want to do it is this: `if($myOption -eq $ValidateSet[1])`. How can this be done?

Thanks

UPDATE:

After looking at Mathias R. Jessen's code I researched enum parameters and managed to achieve what I wanted (with one small limitation described below) by registering enumeration with `Add-Type` (this way not only when you type hyphen after the function name the parameter is listed by ISE but after you type space after that parameter you have ISE displaying list of enum values to choose from). But there's one small problem now: enum is recognized by ISE only if you do `[MyOptions]::someLongLongOption1` inside "if" parentheses but not if you specify this condition inside `switch`. So I would really appreciate if someone explains why that is.

Here is my code:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
 public enum MyOptions {
  someLongLongOption1 = 1,
  someLongLongOption2 = 2,
  someLongLongOption3 = 3
 }
"@

function Get-MyValue
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [MyOptions]$MyOption
  )
    if([MyOptions]::someLongLongOption1 -eq $MyOption){
      Write-Host "option 1"
    }
    else {Write-Host "some option other than option 1"}
}
```

Now if you call the function as `Get-MyValue -MyOption someLongLongOption1` you get `option 1`, when you call the function as `Get-MyValue -MyOption someLongLongOption2` or `Get-MyValue -MyOption someLongLongOption3` you get `some option other than option 1`.

What concerns me is that ISE doesn't recognize `MyOptions` enum when using switch statement instead of if statements. So if you replace if statements with

```
switch($MyOption) {
     [MyOptions]::someLongLongOption1{Write-Host "option 1"}
     default{Write-Host "some option other than option 1"}
    }
```

Not only ISE won't show list of enum identifiers after typing `::`, the function call `Get-MyValue -MyOption someLongLongOption1` would resort to `default` statement rather than appropriate one. Please let me know if you know the reason of this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: If you realllly wanted to, you could reflect over the `ValidateSet` attribute and extract the values into an array. It sounds like a bad idea, though. It's not clear from context at all what `$ValidateSet[1]` is, and worse, if you change the list of options but forget to mirror this exactly in the code, no error will be signaled, but some completely other option value will be used.

Comment: You could use an `enum` type instead

Comment: @JeroenMostert, can I at least provide variables for ValidateSet instead of string literals? That would do.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, and how do I use an `enum` type?

Comment: Nope. `ValidateSet`, as an attribute, accepts constant literals only. Furthermore, PowerShell has no way to declare (true) constants, so you can't assign symbolic names either. An `enum` is the closest thing, but they're not fully equivalent to strings (you're limited in what tag names allow).

Comment: Given the contortionate workarounds you seem to be willing to accept, I've added my original suggestion as an answer. I wouldn't use it myself, but it seems simpler than the other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get the options of a `ValidateSet` into an array? Yes. It's not pretty, but you can.

```
function Get-MyValue
{ 
    param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet("someLongLongOption1",
                     "someLongLongOption2",
                     "someLongLongOption3")]
        $myOption
    )
    $ValidateSet = $MyInvocation.
        MyCommand.
        Parameters["myOption"].
        Attributes.
        Where{$_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute]}.
        ValidValues;

    if ($myOption -eq $ValidateSet[1]) {
        "someLongLongOption2"
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, this is probably the approach that I'd take too, if I were that worried about duplicating the validation set that much...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PowerShell version 5 or newer, you could use an [`enum` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum) instead:

```
function Get-MyValue
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [MyOptions]$MyOption
  )

  begin{
    enum MyOptions {
        someLongLongOption1 = 1
        someLongLongOption2 = 2
        someLongLongOption3 = 3
    }
  }

  end {
    if(1 -eq $MyOption){
      # someLongLongOption1 was chosen
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your function is that (1) for some reason ISE doesn't have parameter MyOption listed when you type hyphen after the function name `Get-MyValue -`, and (2) you typed literal `1` instead of `[MyOptions]::someLongLongOption1` (but that's easy to correct so it's not a big deal, unlike the first issue).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a dynamic parameter which references an array in script scope.  Long-winded, but should support both tab completion in ISE and allow you to reference *something* by index:

```
#region: Module code
$script:getMyValueValidateSet = [String[]] @(
    "someLongLongOption1",
    "someLongLongOption2",
    "someLongLongOption3"
)

Function Get-MyValue
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    DynamicParam {
        $parameters = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

        $myOptionParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $myOptionParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
        $myOptionParameterValidateSet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute -ArgumentList $script:getMyValueValidateSet
        $myOptionParameterAttributes = New-Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]'
        $myOptionParameterAttributes.Add($myOptionParameterAttribute)
        $myOptionParameterAttributes.Add($myOptionParameterValidateSet)
        $myOptionParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter -ArgumentList 'MyOption','String',$myOptionParameterAttributes
        $parameters.Add('MyOption', $myOptionParameter)

        return $parameters
    }
    Begin {
        $MyOption = $PSBoundParameters['MyOption']
    }
    Process {
        $private:i = [Array]::IndexOf($script:getMyValueValidateSet, $MyOption)
        Write-Verbose "You chose: $MyOption, which was option #$private:i"
        Write-Output $script:getMyValueValidateSet[$private:i]
    }
}
#endregion

#region: Test code
Write-Host "`n`nTest help..."
Get-Help Get-MyValue -Detailed

Write-Host "`n`nTest invalid..."
Get-MyValue -MyOption NotValid

Write-Host "`n`nTest valid..."
Get-MyValue -MyOption someLongLongOption2
#endregion
```

Whether the overhead of creating the dynamic parameter is more or less than the duplication of your validation set is for you to decide.

The use-case of `DynamicParam` is really for far more dynamic features than this, but it can be cajoled to doing this simple array lookup.

And, if you put the meat of the above into a module file (e.g. `MyLibrary.psm1`) and do `Import-Module .\MyLibrary.psm1` at the start of your actual script, you don't leak the array to the calling code (because script scope is 'module' scope) but *you* can still reference the array from functions that you define *inside* the MyLibrary.psm1 file.

Comment: What a complex definition. Not sure I'm going to use it but it works.

Comment: What do you call a variable followed with colon (`$script:`)? Never seen it.

Comment: @bp2017: it's a [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).